# How call a django form field from url tag?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a form that I'm using it in order to capture the field values and do a search.
The idea is call template using the "beautiful" url way from django:

mypage.com/search_results/hola

The problem is that I havent got how pass the form field as parameter in the url template.

```
Forms.py
class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    place_display = forms.CharField(max_length=100, help_text='Donde Quieres Ir')

views.py
 def search_results(request,place):
 ..

urls.py
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^search_results/(?P<place>\d+)/$', views.search_results, name='search_results'),
    ..
```

How should I call from url tag in my template if I'm using templates:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="{% url 'search_results' %}" role="form" method="get">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-5">
            <label>Lugar</label>
            {{ form.place_display|add_class:"form-control"}}
            {{ form.place_type }}
            {{ form.place_id }}
        </div>
    </div>

   <div class="controls form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-2">
             <label>Entrada</label>
            {{ form.fromdate|add_class:"form-control"}}

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-2">
            <label>Salida</label>
            {{ form.todate|add_class:"form-control"}}
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
<br />
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Buscar</button>
```

I have try differents ways:

```
action="{% url 'search_results' form.place_display %}"
action="{% url 'search_results' {{form.place_display}} %}"
action="{% url 'search_results' place=form.place_display %}"
etc,etc,etc
```

Answer (score 0):

make `action=''` in the form and, instead, make the redirect inside your view ;)

Here is how your **view** might look:

```
def search_results(request, place):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        place = request.POST.get('place_display','')
        # place_display is the parameter you want, 
        # And '' is the default value if place_display isn't found.


        ### The following return is the thing you want to do, but it is unnatural. 
        ### You can't have an HTML page for any query term a user may search.
        ### What does the 'place' query should actualy do for you?

        return render(request, 'search_results/place', {})
```

instead of this return, what you may realy want to do is the following:

```
return render(request, 'search_results.html', {place: 'place'})
```

Comment: Could you add some more specific detail with a code excerpt?